# Trying to keep numbers in arrays only with 5 digits and only with digits 2,3,5,7

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get rid of all the numbers in my products array which do not have prime numbers or do not have 5 digits. After I splice them in the last for loop, the products array still have numbers that does not satisfy my if condition.

```js
let arr1 = [222, 223, 225 ,227, 232, 233, 235, 237,252, 253, 255, 257, 272, 273, 275, 277, 322, 323, 325, 327, 332, 333, 335, 337, 352, 353, 355, 357, 372, 373, 375, 377, 522, 523, 525, 527, 532, 533, 535, 537, 552,553,555, 557, 572, 573, 575, 577, 722, 723, 725, 727, 732, 733, 735, 737, 752, 753, 755, 757, 772, 773, 775, 777]

let arr2 = [22, 23, 25, 27, 32, 33,35, 37, 52, 53, 55, 57, 72, 73, 75,77]

products = []  
for (var i=0; i< arr1.length; i++){
  for (var j=0; j< arr2.length; j++){
    products.push(arr1[i]*arr2[j])

  }
}
// console.log(products.length);


function not_prime(num){
  var str1 = num.toString()

  if ( 
    str1.indexOf(2) > -1 || 
    str1.indexOf(3) > -1 || 
    str1.indexOf(5) > -1 || 
    str1.indexOf(7) > -1 ||
    str1.length != 5) {
    return false;
    }
  return true;
}

for (var i=0; i< products.length; i++){
  if (not_prime(products[i])) {
    products.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(products)
```

Comment: You should be using `Array.reduce()` or `Array.filter()`.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get rid of non-primes or that you want to get rid of numbers that contain non-prime numbers?

Comment: None of the numbers have 5 digits. No need to keep any of them.

Comment: @StackSlave If you look at his code, he's talking about the `products` array, which is populated by multiplying numbers from the first two arrays. So, the results may well include 5 digit numbers.

Comment: Your Edit only makes what you are trying to do more confusing.

Comment: I want my products array to only have 5 digits and numbers 2,3,5,7. Repetition is allowed.

Comment: Sorry about that! Let me clarify by examples: 
34567 has 6 and 4 on it so it should be removed from product array
33357 is ok
22222 is ok
12235 is not ok as it has 1
235752 is not ok as it has 6 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but take a look at this:

```js
const arr1 = [222, 223, 225 ,227, 232, 233, 235, 237,252, 253, 255, 257, 272, 273, 275, 277, 322, 323, 325, 327, 332, 333, 335, 337, 352, 353, 355, 357, 372, 373, 375, 377, 522, 523, 525, 527, 532, 533, 535, 537, 552,553,555, 557, 572, 573, 575, 577, 722, 723, 725, 727, 732, 733, 735, 737, 752, 753, 755, 757, 772, 773, 775, 777];
const arr2 = [22, 23, 25, 27, 32, 33,35, 37, 52, 53, 55, 57, 72, 73, 75,77];
const products = [];
arr1.forEach(q => {
  arr2.forEach(v => {
    let n = q*v, s = n.toString();
    if(s.length === 5 && s.match(/^[2357]+$/))products.push(n);
  });
});
console.log(products);
```

Comment: But 5575,7755 isn't a prime and neither a 5 digit

Comment: Not really sure what OP wants.

Comment: numbers do not have to be prime but they should contain prime numbers only. However, they have to be 5 digits.

Comment: @StackSlave this code does seem to work. Thanks a lot! Final question, if I want to get the numbers that were multiplied to get the numbers in results, can I just console.log q and v in the forEach loop?
EDIT: I was able to do that. No more help needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) here. See comments inline.

```js
let arr1 = [222, 223, 225 ,227, 232, 233, 235, 237,252, 253, 255, 257, 272, 273, 275, 277, 322, 323, 325, 327, 332, 333, 335, 337, 352, 353, 355, 357, 372, 373, 375, 377, 522, 523, 525, 527, 532, 533, 535, 537, 552,553,555, 557, 572, 573, 575, 577, 722, 723, 725, 727, 732, 733, 735, 737, 752, 753, 755, 757, 772, 773, 775, 777]

let arr2 = [22, 23, 25, 27, 32, 33,35, 37, 52, 53, 55, 57, 72, 73, 75,77];

let primes = [2,3,5,7];

products = []  
for (var i=0; i< arr1.length; i++){
  for (var j=0; j< arr2.length; j++){
    products.push(arr1[i]*arr2[j])

  }
}

// Return a filtered array of products that only contains
// items from the original array that pass the provided callback
// function's tests.
let results = products.filter(function(item){

    // Test to see if item contains primes
    let prime = Array.from(item.toString()).some(function(char){
      return primes.indexOf(+char);
    });

    // Return item only if contains a prime and has 5 digits
    return prime && item.toString().length === 5 ? item : null;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Hey Scott, in the last the return statement you used `&&` but the OP specifies that he needs the number to be prime *OR* a 5 digit number.

Comment: I interpret the requirements (and his initial attempt) to not actually checking for the number to BE prime. It seems to me he wants to check if the number CONTAINS a prime. As for the and/or, I think you're right and will update.

Comment: There are all sorts of numbers that OP doesn't want, I think.

Comment: I want my products array to only have 5 digits and numbers 2,3,5,7. Repetition is allowed.
edit: In other words, the **results** array should only have 5 digit numbers and numbers with digits 2,3,5,7

Comment: @nemo27128 Re-edited back to original to produce AND results.